# How to handle dates in Backbone?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I store dates in the DATETIME format in a MySQL database. When a model is fetched from the database, dates (in the DATETIME format) are converted to date objects in the model's *initialize* method. So far so good.

When the model is saved to the server, the date objects need to be converted back to the DATETIME format in order for the server side code to interpret the dates correctly. I have used all sorts of hackery to do this, but I wonder **at what stage can of the model's *save* method can I safely convert the dates to the DATETIME format?**

One approach is to do the following:

```
this.model.save({
    date : date.toDateTime()
}, options);
```

However, this causes a change event to be fired since the attributes hash before the save method is not the same as the hash after the save event (and this triggers Backbone's set method).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would advice using [UNIX time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (number of seconds/milliseconds from 1970) both in model and in the interface and converting to readable date only in `View`.

So the server both sends and receives dates as numbers like `1328281766454` and this is how you store them in `Backbone.Model`. When it has to be rendered in `View` you can simply call:

```
new Date(this.model.get('someTime'));  //Fri Feb 03 2012 16:09:26 GMT+0100 (CET)
```

The same can be done on the server side. Believe me, this is the simplest and most portable way of transfrering dates without all these time-zone issues.

Comment: Either unix time, or an [ISO standard date representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). I usually use the latter. But I agree that a standard, non-object representation would help the situation.

Comment: That is an option I have considered, but it creates quite a bit of overhead by creating a date object every time you need one. A consistent date representation would indeed make things much easier though.

Comment: You convinced me, Tomasz (and Rob). It will take a bit of work, but I see the benefit of having a date format that is independent of the environment/language. Thanks a lot for your time Tomasz and Rob. Much appreciated.

Comment: Depending on what you're doing, the time zone is important data for your user. A unix timestamp isn't a one-size-fits-all solution.

Comment: @DanJackson In your experience, is the unix timestamp problematic in that it loses timezone information?

Comment: @tomasz Do you create all timestamps with an implicit UTC time zone (offset 0)?

Comment: @AlanH. Exactly. I think it's actually domain specific, and Tomasz's solution is often correct. Counter-example: I tell your webapp I just had a child, at 1328281766454. I currently live in Sydney, Australia. Two years from now, I move to the US. What day is my child's bday, according to your app?

For me, it was Saturday Feb 4th, at 2am local time when my child was born. But if you use 1328281766454 relative to my current time zone, you'd tell me he was born on Feb 3rd, which is really going to confuse me.

Comment: Another counter example: If the user asks to be reminded of something next Saturday at noon, and then they change timezones ahead one hour. Do they want a reminder at 1pm (all you can tell from the unix time), or should it still happen at noon? Essentially, consider whether you need the instant in time ignoring the time zone, or if the time zone is important for relating the time to the user. PS: sorry about multiple comments.

Answer (score 9):

I'd do it one of two places:

- On the server:

  This probably makes the most sense, since your server-side implementation is really the one that needs the DATETIME representation; your client code shouldn't have to care at all.
- In `toJSON()` on your model:

  If you *must* do it on the client, override `Backbone.Model`'s [`toJSON()`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-toJSON) for your model and update it there. Example:

  ```
  toJSON: function () {
      var json = Backbone.Model.prototype.toJSON.call(this);
      json.date = convertDate(this.get('date'));
      return json;
  }
  ```

  If you do this, you'll need to convert the date back, either in your model's [`initialize()`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-constructor) or [`parse()`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-parse) function.

Comment: I totally agree that the best place is to do it on the server side, but I don't think it is possible to convert a JavaScript date object to a DATETIME with PHP.

Comment: @BartJacobs - I'm sure it is, it's just a matter of how much work you'd have to do to accomplish it. You'd just have to build up the PHP `date()` or SQL `DATETIME` from the JSON object's properties.

Comment: To simplify and clarify a bit. In parse: `data.date = uiDate(data.date);` and in toJSON: `json.date = isoDate(json.date);`

Answer (score 7):

May not be the answer your looking for - but have seen folks use moment.js to format time in backbone -

http://momentjs.com/